# I am trying to use two different async definitions (@client.event and @bot.command()) however one of them doesn't work

Tags: python, discord.py

So the more specific explanation is simple. I have both command and on_message. In my code the command in question is for making the bot join a voice chat.

The command part doesn't work

Code snippet

[image]

Too much to list

I expect both my on_message() commands and my @bot.command() join function to work in the same file, but they don't

Comment: Request you to update image code to normal text so someone can copy or edit if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on_message` event function is blocking the commands, to unblock it you have to use `await bot.process_commands(message)`

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
   await bot.process_commands(message)
```

EDIT: Did not notice that you had both client and bot until `Marinus Bokslag` had mentioned it and as suggested, you can't really have both at the same time since the client or the bot has to be ran for the code to work.

Comment: So just to clarify, client and bot do use the same basic functions right? (Meaning can I run a bot "client" (discord.Bot) as the the actual client user?) Also I only just now realized what you meant, the "@client.command()" was from a separate test file, in the context of the file that screenshot is from, it's "@bot.command()"

Comment: Everything a client can do, the bot can do, but the client can't do what bot can do. Bot can make commands via `@bot.command(pass_context=True`;async def func name(ctx):pass;`. Attributes and functions of the bot can be found [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/bot.py)